# Excel Array using Combin

Tags: microsoft-excel

In cells `A1:C1` I have the numbers 8, 3, and 5. In cell `D1` I would like to automatically sum the number of combinations like so:

```
=COMBIN($A1,3)+COMBIN($A1,4)+COMBIN($A1,5)
```

If C1 was 6 instead of 5, then I would want:

```
=COMBIN($A1,3)+COMBIN($A1,4)+COMBIN($A1,5)+COMBIN($A1,6)
```

If C1 was instead 1, then I would want:

```
=COMBIN($A1,3)+COMBIN($A1,2)+COMBIN($A1,1)
```

So in other words, I'd like B1 to be the target number of samples that C1 heads towards in the D1 formula.

Comment: Are you open to using VBA in your solution? (I deleted my previous answer because it was totally wrong)

Comment: I was able to get a solution from another forum, thanks for your time. In D1: =SUMPRODUCT(COMBIN(A1,ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&C1))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COMBIN(A1,ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&C1))))
```

In this formula `ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&C1))` generates an array of integers from `B1` to `C1` (in your example that will be `{3;4;5}`) and with this array applied as the second argument of `COMBIN` you'll then get an array result from `COMBIN` which `SUMPRODUCT` sums to give your result

This works whether `B1` < `C1` or not, e.g. you get the same result if `B1` = `1` and `C1` = `3` as you would with `B1` = `3` and `C1` = `1`

Comment: This was the same solution I received from another forum. Thank Barry, it works prefectly. And thanks for the explanation. I'll be able to apply this to other tasks.